# Using Jcarousellite and Fancybox on same slideshow

Tags: jquery, fancybox, slideshow, jcarousellite

I'm trying to use fancybox and jcarousellite on the same slideshow.  I have gotten both scripts working independently, but when I put them together neither work.

I am thinking it might be the scripts that are conflicting, but I've seen other websites that use both functions.

Here is what I have in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("a#fancy").fancybox();
 });
 </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {

$(".home").jCarouselLite({
btnNext: ".next",
btnPrev: ".prev",
visible: 1,
speed: 1000,
 auto: 2000,
easing: "easeinout"
});
});
</script>
```

Then my images are laid out like this:

```
<div id="slider" class="home" style="margin-top:-30px;">
<ul>
                <li ><a class="fancy" href="image"><img src="image" alt="Modern Wedding Photographer" style="padding:5px; border:0;"/></a></li>
<li ><a class="fancy" href="image"><img src="image" alt="Modern Wedding Photographer" style="padding:5px; border:0;"/></a></li>
<li ><a class="fancy" href="image"><img src="image" alt="Modern Wedding Photographer" style="padding:5px; border:0;"/></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution?
Thanks

Comment: fancybox script is included ? I can see carouse and jquery, fancybox.js was renamed  in jquery.js ?

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi I think my attempt to include all the code got messed up.

Comment: The fancybox script is included.  It's jquery.min.js and jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js taken directly from their how to section on their website. http://fancybox.net/howto